# which function odoo 13 replace _prepare_refund in account.move

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

Which function odoo 13 replace _prepare_refund() in account.invoice  that prepare refund values in account.move Please

Answer (score 1):

For credit note, you can track method *"_reverse_moves"* and for debit note, *"create_debit"* method.

Additionally, track *"prepare_default_values"* method for preparing values.

Comment: Hi i have found it in case of someone else need it  _reverse_move_vals()